# Specialise method-parameter in child-class in VB.Net /C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance

I wrote some wrapper classes for standardize working with database. So I wrote a class for accessing a mssql-db and one for oledb. I want the both to look as much as possible the same. So for example this is my **base class**:

```
Public MustInherit Class SqlBase

    Public MustOverride Sub ExecuteSelectStatement(ByVal Statement As String, ByVal ParamArray Parameters As DbParameter())

End Class
```

And now I want to specialise it in **child class** the following way:

```
Public Class mssql
    Inherits SqlBase

    Public Overrides Sub ExecuteSelectStatement(Statement As String, ParamArray Parameters() As SqlParameter)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

where **SqlParameter itself inherits from DbParameter**. Unfortunaly this approach doesn't seems to work.

Is there any way to specialise the parameters of a method with types which are inherited from the parameters of the base class. I only found a solution using generics which seems not to be straight forward in my case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use  just ParamArray Parameters without casting in both cases? You can cast inside of your sub.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. If you want to override a member then it has to actually be that member you override. One thing you can do is implement as much as you can in the base class and then have each overridden method do the specialised stuff and then call the base method.

Comment: "I only found a solution using generics which seems not to be straight forward in my case." - What is not straight forward with `Public MustInherit Class SQLBase(Of T_Parameter As {Class, IDbDataParameter})` and then `Public MustOverride Sub ExecuteSelectStatement(ByVal Statement As String, ByVal ParamArray Parameters As T_Parameter())`.  Then the derived class would be `Public Class MSSql : Inherits SQLBase(Of SqlClient.SqlParameter)`

Comment: Great  point. The possibility to limit the type inserted for an generic is new to me. I think this will be a good approach. Thanks.